# How to set ',' as decimal separator with R

Tags: r, separator

Even though my Windows 7 locale settings specify using "," as a decimal separator, R and RStudio give me a "." separator. Is there any way to change this? Note the "LC_NUMERIC=C" setting in the locale below: this seems to be forced by R or RStudio.

As I am in the middle of a long project, I am unwilling to change right away to R 3.0 and the last RStudio version. Does anybody know is there is any change regarding the decimal separator issue in these versions?

I am using prettyNum to solve the problem for single numbers, but I don't know how to use it on a table.

sessionInfo()
    R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Argentina.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Argentina.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Argentina.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Argentina.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ascii_2.1          randomForest_4.6-7 pander_0.3.3       fpc_2.1-5         
 [5] flexmix_2.3-10     mclust_4.0         cluster_1.14.3     MASS_7.3-23       
 [9] Gmisc_0.5.0.0      testthat_0.7       boot_1.3-7         rms_3.6-3         
[13] miscTools_0.6-16   stringr_0.6.2      Hmisc_3.10-1       survival_2.37-2   
[17] lattice_0.20-13    xtable_1.7-1       pixmap_0.4-11      RColorBrewer_1.0-5
[21] ade4_1.5-1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3      evaluate_0.4.3    modeltools_0.2-19 stats4_2.15.3    
[5] tools_2.15.3
```

Comment: Which "table" do you mean? How do you create it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The decimal separator used by the `read.table` and `write.table` functions (and most of their cousins) is set with "dec" parameter. `read.csv2` is a special case where the default for `dec` is "," and the field separator ("sep") is set to ";".

You *can* change the output from R  printing, plotting and the actions of the `as.character` function. You change it from its default with:

```
 options(OutDec= ",")   # read ?options
 print( pi )
 #[1] 3,141593
 options(OutDec= ",")  # restore default value
```

This will NOT cause R to handle numeric input from the console differently. That is hard-coded to "." as the decimal separator.

If you applied a text function to a table object, you would be possibly coercing from a 'numeric' to a 'character' mode, since table objects in R inherit from the "matrix" class.

It should be added that the "natural" way to read data with "europian" decimal separators is to use `read.delim`. Not only does it change the decimal separator to "," but at the same time it changes some the parameters to something other than the default for read.table or read.csv:

```
sep = "\t", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = ""
```

Comment: Wonderful!! This is better than the first answer, with which I was having problems in some tables... Is it OK to change the 'answered' mark?

Comment: this had no effect whatsoever, I had to instead change my locale for printing numbers with `Sys.setlocale("LC_NUMERIC","C")` (I'm using linux)

Comment: @jena Seems likely that you were dealing with output to something other than the R console. As far as I know, the R console is completely consistent across locales.

Comment: @42- I had an issue with plotting. From the `help(options)` I understood that this should work but it didn't. Edit: actually no, there was no effect also in console (I use SublimeREPL plugin for Sublime-Text).

Comment: @jena : I cannot tell what code was being used and so saying "issue with plotting" will not allow any specific advice other than to say the interface to graphics devices is often OS and device specific. For a specific answer you may need to post a question with a [MCVE]

Comment: @42- Well I had commas as decimals in my plot axes after any `plot()` call. Locale was set to czech, so comma was correct, but I needed to change it for publication. The `options()` function didn't work, as it didn't work with the `pi` example.

Comment: @jen I still do not know what was done. Posing a separate question in comments is not an effective way of getting answers. I say ... again .... post a question with a [MCVE]

Comment: @42- sorry I was not asking a question, just commenting to add an information that the solution in this answer doesn't work in some circumstances.. as I mentioned in my first comment I already solved it with different method

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use "," as decimal separator, in that case how R will interprate this R expression

```
x <- c(2,3) # (two vectors or one).
```

So, I assume that you just want to override the default decimal separator to print an output and in this case, I think prettyNum is the right tool.

```
require(plyr)
head(numcolwise(prettyNum)(iris, dec = ","))

##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
## 1          5,1         3,5          1,4         0,2
## 2          4,9           3          1,4         0,2
## 3          4,7         3,2          1,3         0,2
## 4          4,6         3,1          1,5         0,2
## 5            5         3,6          1,4         0,2
## 6          5,4         3,9          1,7         0,4
```

Comment: Yes, I only need it for the output. I have never used plyr before and didn't know the numcolwise funtion. Thank you!

Comment: @dickoa. That is a European convention. The dec parameter is only used for inpout and output from/to text files. As you note, there is no option for changing value and decimal separators within R, but that wasn't really the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you want to use it with (Pandoc) markdown as far as I can see from the [blog comment where you referenced this question](http://www.surefoss.org/publishing-publizieren/all-you-need-is-text-markdown-via-pandoc-for-academia/#comment-1035), I would also suggest to give a try to my [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/):

```
> library(pander)
> panderOptions('decimal.mark', ',')
> panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
> pander(head(iris))

-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width   Species 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
     5,1            3,5           1,4            0,2       setosa  

     4,9             3            1,4            0,2       setosa  

     4,7            3,2           1,3            0,2       setosa  

     4,6            3,1           1,5            0,2       setosa  

      5             3,6           1,4            0,2       setosa  

     5,4            3,9           1,7            0,4       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or PHP Markdown Extra syntax for easier usage with `knitr`:

```
> pandoc.table(head(iris), style = 'rmarkdown')


|  Sepal.Length  |  Sepal.Width  |  Petal.Length  |  Petal.Width  |  Species  |
|:--------------:|:-------------:|:--------------:|:-------------:|:---------:|
|      5,1       |      3,5      |      1,4       |      0,2      |  setosa   |
|      4,9       |       3       |      1,4       |      0,2      |  setosa   |
|      4,7       |      3,2      |      1,3       |      0,2      |  setosa   |
|      4,6       |      3,1      |      1,5       |      0,2      |  setosa   |
|       5        |      3,6      |      1,4       |      0,2      |  setosa   |
|      5,4       |      3,9      |      1,7       |      0,4      |  setosa   |
```