# Converting dot to comma in numeric

Tags: r, decimal, number-formatting

If I have a data frame:

```
a   b  
2.4 4.6
3.6 66.7
5.8 44.6
```

Both a and b are numeric.

I want to convert "." to "," with

```
df$a <- as.numeric(gsub(".", ",", df$a))
```

but I always get

```
Warning message:NAs introduced by coercion
```

and all values are converted to NA. Why?

Comment: Do you mean you still want numeric values, but you want the `.` to be `,`?

Comment: Exactly. Is that possible?

Comment: Finnish (Finland). And the decimal separator is comma.

Comment: Well, let's be clear...a number is a number, and has no dot or comma, what you probably want is to change how you see those numbers when you print them. So you want "format" your numbers with commas... is this correct?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your initial idea was almost correct, just regular expression was wrong, because `.` matches any symbol. You need something like (this will convert numeric vector to a character vector)

```
df$a <- gsub("\\.", ",", df$a)
```

Also you can change the output from R printing, plotting and the actions of the as.character function. You change it from its default with:

`options(OutDec= ",")`

And another option is using `format` function.

```
format(df, decimal.mark=",")
```

I assume that you care about how numbers are printed (output), because internally numeric is stored as a double precision floating point number (**Update** thanks to comment by @digemall). Also unless for some function like `read.table` it is specifically specified that decimal separator is `,`, it's not possible to do otherwise, because by default `,` is used for separating function arguments.

And `NA` are introduced exactly for that reason (aside from incorrect regex).

```
df$a <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.", ",", df$a))
```

By default parser does not know that `,` is used as a decimal separator.

Comment: Seems like the `options` part is definitely what the OP needs.

Comment: This converts "." to ",". Good! The thing is that what I am actually trying to achieve is to export a large file of geographic coordinates. The program that handles the coordinates doesn't recognize them as such if they are in character format. I will check later whether the program accepts this solution.

Comment: If you are exporting data with something like `write.csv` then you have to use it with additional *dec* parameter like so: `write.csv(data, file=file, dec=",")`

Comment: @romantsegelskyi: _- internally it is always stored with . for decimal separator -_  that's not correct. A numeric is stored using IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point standard on 64 bit, and there's no "dot" symbol (simply 1 bit represent the sign, 11 bits the exponent and 52 the fraction) See this [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: What's the role of `\\\` before the dot?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want commas for printing, you can use format:

```
data <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=rnorm(5))
format(data, decimal.mark=",")
              a          b
1   1,058878354  0,1812629
2   1,026163906 -0,6666500
3   1,538423889 -1,4206752
4  -0,561585916 -0,4729558
5  -0,004685406  1,0744514
```

However this will only change how they look. You will still have to use dots in assigns.

Comment: If you want to permanently set the output to look like this, [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384836/how-to-set-as-decimal-separator-with-r-rstudio). You can use `options(OutDec= ",")`.

Comment: But this converts those numeric to character, right? I would need the values to be numeric and with ","

Comment: Here is the thing: the computer stores does numbers in very different ways than you seem them. With this you can change how R presents the numbers to you. They will be numeric, but when printed on screen they will have that comma instead of a dot. For input I suspect that you cannot change dot to a comma. Consider this `c(1,2,3,4)`. Now how would interpreter know if it's 1 2 3 and 4 or 1.2 and 3.4 ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you on OSX or Windows or ...?

To change the representation, you want to look at the `LC_NUMERIC` parameter, although R documentation warns that changing this may cause R to operate strangely (hard to use `,` as decimal when it is also used to define lists...)

```
> Sys.getlocale("LC_NUMERIC")
[1] "C"
> a=c(1.01,2.01)
> a
[1] 1.01 2.01
> Sys.setlocale("LC_NUMERIC", "de_DE") # this is OSX syntax
> a
[1] 1,01 2,01
```

Might be safer just to live with it!