# How to convert dot in comma in data.frame

Tags: r, decimal

I would like to convert the dot (decimal separator) to comma as decimal separator.
I tried using `format(decimal.mark=",")` but got an error.

```
 df<-structure(list(ponto = c("F01", "F02", "F03", "F04", "F05", "F06"
 ), `Vegetação Nativa` = c(0.09, 3.12, 8.22, 5.92, 1.95, 4.7), 
     Agricultura = c(91.78, 91.87, 100, 100, 91.5, 99.38), Pastagem = c(-16.99, 
     -33.16, -22.73, -24.12, -38, -47.3), `Área Urbana` = c(27.32, 
     27.32, 27.57, 27.57, 19.18, NaN), `Solo Exposto` = c(10.04, 
     2.13, 8.5, 6.64, -29.35, -442.86), `Corpo Hídrico` = c(-15.62, 
     -15.62, NaN, NaN, -17.11, -25.93)), class = c("grouped_df", 
 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
     ponto = c("F01", "F02", "F03", "F04", "F05", "F06"), .rows = structure(list(
         1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
     "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I tried this, but got an error:

```
df%>%
  format(decimal.mark=",")
```

Comment: 1) I cannot reproduce your error. Your code runs, although the format is not as expected. 2) Your dataframe is a `tibble`, whose `format` method does not support using an alternative decimal mark. 3) If you want to use comma as the decimal mark for print, try `df %>% format.data.frame(decimal.mark = ",")`

Comment: I did `df%>%as.data.frame()%>%format.data.frame(decimal.mark = ",")` and it worked, but converted the columns to characters.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was your requirement? AFAIK, It is not possible in R to set the decimal mark to ",". If you really want that, you can do so when you **print** the numbers. That line of code is supposed to be used as a customized way of printing. Any returned value from it is not supposed to be used for further computations. @wesleysc352

Comment: Numeric values will always display  at the console with periods as decimal points. You can always format them to to have character representation with commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `mutate` and `across` from `dplyr`. Though this will still change their type to `character`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), format, decimal.mark = ","))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
# Groups:   ponto [6]
  ponto `Vegetação Nativa` Agricultura Pastagem `Área Urbana` `Solo Exposto` `Corpo Hídrico`
  <chr> <chr>              <chr>       <chr>    <chr>         <chr>          <chr>          
1 F01   0,09               91,78       -16,99   27,32         10,04          -15,62         
2 F02   3,12               91,87       -33,16   27,32         2,13           -15,62         
3 F03   8,22               100         -22,73   27,57         8,5            NaN            
4 F04   5,92               100         -24,12   27,57         6,64           NaN            
5 F05   1,95               91,5        -38      19,18         -29,35         -17,11         
6 F06   4,7                99,38       -47,3    NaN           -442,86        -25,93
```

Additionally, if you are wanting to simply change how you are seeing the data while printing, plotting, etc. for anything that is `as.character`, then you can change the default options. You can also read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27158388/15293191) (this post has a lot of discussion directly related to your question).

```
options(OutDec= ",")
```

Examples (after changing options):

```
c(1.5, 3.456, 40000.89)

# [1]     1,500     3,456 40000,890
```

However, the caveat is that the data must be character. So with your data, we could convert those to character, then they will display with the comma rather than period.

```
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character))

# A tibble: 6 × 7
# Groups:   ponto [6]
  ponto `Vegetação Nativa` Agricultura Pastagem `Área Urbana` `Solo Exposto` `Corpo Hídrico`
  <chr> <chr>              <chr>       <chr>    <chr>         <chr>          <chr>          
1 F01   0,09               91,78       -16,99   27,32         10,04          -15,62         
2 F02   3,12               91,87       -33,16   27,32         2,13           -15,62         
3 F03   8,22               100         -22,73   27,57         8,5            NaN            
4 F04   5,92               100         -24,12   27,57         6,64           NaN            
5 F05   1,95               91,5        -38      19,18         -29,35         -17,11         
6 F06   4,7                99,38       -47,3    NaN           -442,86        -25,93
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I did as you said, but the columns changed from numeric to character format.

Comment: @wesleysc352 As far as I am aware (and based on that other post I linked to), I don't think it is possible to have a `numeric` value with a comma rather than a decimal.