# How can I divide several entire numbers separated by a comma in one column by numbers in another column

Tags: r

I wanted to divide numbers separated by commas in a column 
by other numbers.
Here is the input I have

```
> df = data.frame (SAMPLE1.DP=c("555","651","641","717"), SAMPLE1.AD=c("555", "68,583","2,639","358,359"), SAMPLE2.DP=c("1023","930","683","1179"), SAMPLE2.AD=c("1023","0,930","683","585,594"))
> df
  SAMPLE1.DP SAMPLE1.AD SAMPLE2.DP SAMPLE2.AD
1        555        555       1023       1023
2        651      68,583        930      0,930
3        641      2,639        683        683
4        717    358,359       1179    585,594
```

In the end I want to add two new columns (AD/DP) that divide the values SAMPLE1.AD by SAMPLE1.DP AND SAMPLE2.AD by SAMPLE2.DP, which represent pourcentage of numbers at each side of the comma, like this :

```
> end = data.frame(SAMPLE1.DP=c("555","651","641","717"),
+ SAMPLE1.AD=c("555", "68,583","204,437","358,359"),
+ SAMPLE1.AD_DP=c("1.00","0.10,0.90","0.32,0.68","0.50,0.50"),
+ SAMPLE2.DP=c("1023","930","683","1179"),
+ SAMPLE2.AD=c("1023","0,930","683","585,594"),
+ SAMPLE2.AD_DP=c("1.00","0.00,1.00","1.00","0.49,0,51"))
>end
  SAMPLE1.DP SAMPLE1.AD SAMPLE1.AD_DP SAMPLE2.DP SAMPLE2.AD SAMPLE2.AD_DP
1        555        555             1.00       1023       1023             1.00
2        651     68,583     0.10,0.90        930      0,930           0.00,1.00
3        641    204,437     0.32,0.68        683        683             1.00
4        717    358,359       0.50,0.50       1179    585,594     0.49,0,51
```

it means :
XX YY,ZZ YY/XX,ZZ/XX AA BB,CC BB/AA,CC/AA

If I consider the values inside the table as.numeric, it does not work since values are separated by commas...

Do you have any idea to do this ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Am I seeing things, or did an extra row magically appear in your output?

Comment: Hi @lucky_luk_95, it would be very helpful for us if you share what you have tried since now to solve your problem. At any rate, I think that you have to set which is the decimal separator for your number (get a glance at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384836/how-to-set-as-decimal-separator-with-r)

Comment: @Tim Biegelesien. Thanks you are right, an extra row appeared on the first line of my expected output, sorry. It was a copy/paste mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is replace the `,` with `.` and cast to numeric. Then split based on your required condition and divide, i.e.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(i)as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', i)))
do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df, gsub('\\D+', '', names(df))), function(i) i[2] / i[1]))
#   SAMPLE1.AD SAMPLE2.AD
#1 1.000000000   1.000000
#2 0.004066052   0.001000
#3 0.004117005   1.000000
#4 0.499803347   0.496687
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are commas in your numbers than the column has most likely been poisoned and is cast as characters. What you need to do is convert your columns to numeric and then divide each column respectively.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(~"SAMPLE1.DP",  ~"SAMPLE1.AD",  ~"SAMPLE2.DP",  ~"SAMPLE2.AD",
            555,              555,             1023,           1023,
            651,              "2,647",           930,          ",93",
            641,              "2,639",          683,           683,
            717,              "358,359",         1179,       "585,594")

dat %>% 
    mutate_at(c(2,4), list(~str_replace(., ",", "."))) %>% 
    mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% 
    mutate(addp1 = SAMPLE1.AD / SAMPLE1.DP,
           addp2 = SAMPLE2.AD / SAMPLE2.DP)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   SAMPLE1.DP SAMPLE1.AD SAMPLE2.DP SAMPLE2.AD   addp1 addp2
#>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        555     555          1023    1023    1       1    
#> 2        651       2.65        930       0.93 0.00407 0.001
#> 3        641       2.64        683     683    0.00412 1    
#> 4        717     358.         1179     586.   0.500   0.497
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I guess you converted the numbers wrong..... you turned `0,93` into `93` The OP just needs to replace the `,` by `.` as done by @Sotos and pointed out by@Scipione Sarlo

Comment: @CodeNoob Ahh I see, I turned 930 to 9300 and 0.93 to 93 by pushing the 0 to the previous number. Didn't realize they were using commas as decimal separators.

Comment: Edited my answer to handle commas as decimal delimiters.

Comment: thanks @dylanjm. I have cleaned up my input. 0,930 means 0 AND 930. I have no decimal but comma separating 2 distinct numbers, that is the challenge ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone but I was not very clear in my question, very sorry.

In my input example, I have only whole numbers separated by commas, no decimales.

For example, on line 3 of my example :
2,647 means 2 AND 647, and I want to divide both numbers by 651 in order to have as result : 2/651 , 647/651 , so it will be 0.01 and 0.99 (or 1% and 99%)

They are entire numbers (or integers), separated by commas.

Hope I am clearer ...thanks...

Comment: You need to create a sample dataframe and edit your question to include this. Don't just paste the output but either 1) create a sample dataframe that we can easily copy/paste into our script or 2) run `dput(df)` where df is the current dataframe you're working with and paste the output of that command into your question. Also, best not to post an answer to your own question providing updates. It's better to edit your original question.

Comment: thanks dylanjm, I have updated the post as you recommanded. Thx