# running code with dplyr::filter gives error "must be a logical vector, not the number 5."

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run this code:

```r
data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowth)

filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0,5)
```

but the following error is causing me problems:

> Error in `filter()`:
> ℹ In argument: `5`.
> Caused by error:
> ! `..2` must be a logical vector, not the number 5.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I have already run the following in the RStudio console:

```r
> install.packages("dplyr")
> library(dplyr)
```

Comment: Typo.  `dose == 0.5` or `dose %in% c(1, 5)` depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try ```filtered_tg <- ToothGrowth %>% filter(dose == 0 | dose == 5)``` (or 0.5 if that's what you meant).

Comment: @Limey, not sure whether this is a typo or a decimal-separator-convention issue.

Comment: change 0,5 to 0.5 (commat to point).

Comment: @BenBolker  Agreed.  I have to admit the error message is one of R's more obscure observations...

Comment: @Limey, R can't really help it -- this messes up the parser in a way that would be difficult to detect reliably.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possibilities here.

1. This is a simple typo, you meant to type `0.5` instead of `0,5`.
2. You are confused about decimal separator conventions. This has the same solution, but is a different conceptual problem.

   R uses the North American convention where `.`, not `,` is used as a decimal separator.  Specify the dose value as `0.5`, not `0,5`.

```r
filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5)
```

As R uses a comma for lots of other things, this is a setting you can't change.  (You *can* change it for the purpose of reading and writing data, e.g. see the `read.csv2()` function, or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384836/how-to-set-as-decimal-separator-with-r).)

3. You are trying to specify two different possible values for `dose` (in which case you should use `dose == 0 | dose == 5` or `dose %in% c(0,5)` as your criterion).  (This seems implausible but was mentioned by commenters.)

Comment: In my mind it is obvious, that it is a typo because there are only 3 values for dose (0.5, 1.0, 2.0). But anyway I find the way you think very interesting!

Comment: I find the third option (decimal separator confusion) most plausible (I agree that the `dose %in% c(0,5)` explanation is unlikely; I put it in because commenters raised it).

Answer (score 0):

filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
View(filtered_tg)

received :

Error in filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5) : object 'dose' not found

> 

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).